Can't ping USRP N210 from Ubuntu VM ver 22.04.3
I'm trying to install and use GNURadio with USRP N210 on my windows 11 PC
I've installed Ubuntu ver 22.04.3 and GNURadio and both work except for recognizing the URSP
I have a point to point ethernet connection from my network card (eth0) to the USRP.
Previously tried a USB to ethernet adapter to the USRP but I've now moved that to ethernet 2 and it works for external internet.  Here is the output of ipconfig from my windows command prompt:
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ae3e:1b39:9087:5d77%24
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.30.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.va.comcast.net
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:5cc:c801:8f40::afb2
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:5cc:c801:8f40:ba76:6d86:9a63:4618
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2601:5cc:c801:8f40:f9a1:7fb6:414e:d4f3
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::be99:829:3e5e:346f%7
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.65
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::a2ff:70ff:fed0:bd92%7
10.0.0.1
I can ping my USRP at 192.168.30.2 from a windows command prompt but can't ping from the Ubuntu terminal.  So I know the USRP and physical connections are good.
I configured the Ubuntu network by changing /etc/network/interface to:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.30.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.30.0    //I also had no gateway here and tried 192.168.30.1
ip a shows:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000  
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00    
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo    
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever    
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host    
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000  
    link/ether 00:15:5d:20:80:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  
    inet 192.168.30.1/24 brd 192.168.30.255 scope global eth0  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe20:80b8/64 scope link  
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever  

I can ping 192.168.30.1 but I get no response when I ping the USRP at 192.168.30.2
I've scoured the internet and tried various things but no luck.  Please help.
Thanks in advance, Rich
